# Surface equivalent of catenary curve

Tags: calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, geometric-analysis, recreational-mathematics, reference-request

A [catenary curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary)
is the shape taken by an idealized hanging chain or rope under the influence
of gravity.  It has the equation $y= a \cosh (x/a)$.
My question is:

> What is the shape taken by an idealized, thin two-dimensional sheet,
>   pinned on a plane parallel to the ground, under the influence of gravity?

The answer surely depends on how it is pinned to the plane, the boundary
conditions.
Natural options are:

- A disk sheet fixed to a circle.
- A square sheet fixed to a square.
- A square sheet pinned at its four corners.

The middle option above would look something like this when inverted:

---

[image: CatDome]

          

<sup>(Image by Tim Tyler at [hexdome.com](http://hexdome.com/essays/catenary_domes/gallery/index.html).)</sup>

---

I don't think any of these shapes is a
[catenoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenoid),
which is the surface of revolution formed by a catenary curve.
Is there a simple analytic description of any of these surfaces,
analogous to the $\cosh$ equation for the catenary curve?
I have been unsuccessful in finding anything but simulations of solutions
of the differential equations.

This question arose in imagining a higher-dimensional version
of the property that an inverted catenary supports smooth rides of a square-wheeled
bicycle
(explored in [this MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29988/) question).
Thanks for pointers!

Comment: How is the surface allowed to deform in the interior?  Area preserving?  Conformal?  Preserving the volume of the region is incloses? (Like a soap film, but with gravity taken into account.)

Comment: Keivn, good point. For example, a rotated catenary surface is quite simply not isometric to a flat disc. So we might, for instance, be asking about a rubber sheet in the shape of a disc, glued down along a circular boundary, and allowed to sag in the middle under gravity. The elastic  energy less resembles the mean curvature operator in favor of the ordinary Laplacian.   

Comment: @Kevin,Will: Good questions! I had imagined a thin bedsheet, or loose chain mail. In the above image, the hexagon edge lengths are fixed, so it is akin to chain mail.

Comment: Dear Joseph. AS mentioned by others, your problem is somewhat ill-posed... Are you trying to minimize the energy of a surface or of a parametrized surface? Are you fixing the area of the surface? Does the energy contain only a potential term, or does it also contain a term having to do with the derivative of the parametrizing map? For the last question "a square sheet pinned at its four corners": is the length of the free boundary fixed?... ...

Comment: @André: Point well-taken!  I guess the model in the image is closest: tesselate the surface with identical polygons, each composed of rigid links joined at universal joints.  Maintain the length of each link, allowing rotation at the joints.  This is analogous to a hanging chain composed of rigid links connected
at rotatable joints.  It would approximate woven cloth of a certain
constitution.

Comment: @Joseph. In that case, your surface is likely to behave in an anisotropic way, which will make the problem much more complicated... I would recommend staying within the realm of differential geometry (as opposed to Finslerian geometry???).

Comment: @Joseph: I took the liberty of adding variational-calculus and geometric-analysis tags.

Comment: Hello Joseph, I am going to talk about a variation of your problem at the upcoming MAA Seaway meeting in Hamilton College on April 14. Regards, Victor.

Comment: @Victor: Good luck! (I'm afraid I cannot attend myself.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A model equation for an inextensible, ﬂexible, heavy surface  in a gravitational ﬁeld was deduced by <s>Poisson</s> Lagrange and later the problem was  also studied by Poisson (see the references in the linked papers below). The equilibrium condition for a hanging heavy surface of constant mass density reads 
$$\sqrt{1+|\nabla u|^2}\ \nabla\cdot{}\frac{\nabla u}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla u|^2}}=\frac{1}{u+\lambda},\qquad x\in\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2,\qquad\qquad(1)$$
where $u=u(x)$ is the vertical displacement and $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ is an arbitrary constant (a Lagrange multiplier). (1) is the Euler equation of the variational integral
$$I(u)=\int_{\Omega}u\sqrt{1+|\nabla u|^2}dx,$$
which can be interpreted as the vertical coordinate of the center of gravity of the surface
$$\mbox{graph}(u)=\{(x,u(x)):\ x\in\Omega\}\subset\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R.$$

Equation (1) is to be supplemented with the requirement that the surface has a prescribed area $A$
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\int_{\Omega}\sqrt{1+|\nabla u|^2}dx=A,\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\quad(2) $$
and the Dirichlet boundary condition describing the curve from which the surface is being suspended
$$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\left.u\right|_{\partial \Omega}=g.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad(3) $$
One can check formally that a solution to (1)-(3) provides a graph of a heavy surface of prescribed area and boundary with the lowest center of gravity, so this is a precise 2D analogue of the classical catenary problem.

It is known that problem (1)-(3) has no classical solutions for the values of area $A$ outside of some bounded interval $[A_{\min},A_{\max}]$. Moreover, the corresponding variational problem has no global solutions for all $A\in\mathbb R$. A short survey of some old and relatively new results concerning well-posedness of (1)-(3) and its multidimensional analogues can be found in the paper by Dierkes and Huisken, "The N-dimensional analogue of the catenary: Prescribed area", in J. Jost (ed) *Calculus of Variations and Geometric Analysis*, Int. Press (1996), pp. 1-13.

**Addendum.** Here is a more recent survey by Dierkes: ["Singular Minimal Surfaces"](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Q6K-FIsH6RQC&oi=fnd&pg=PA177&ots=9DdAcwoC_Q&sig=cW8HIdpH7fT09i2SskuHl3S64SE#v=onepage&q&f=false) (in *Geometric Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations*, Springer (2003),  pp. 177-194).

Comment: @Andrey: That link is broken but you must mean this: 
"The $n$-dimensional analogue of the catenary: Existence and nonexistence,"
U. Dierkes and G. Huisken,
_Pacific J. Math._, Volume 141, Number 1 (1990), 47-54. http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.pjm/1102646773 
This seems exactly what I sought---Thanks so much!

Comment: @Joseph: Thank you, I've replaced the broken link with a reference. Actually, I referred to a different, more recent publication with a similar title (please see the corrected answer). 

Comment: I believe the humble cone is a solution to this (with circular boundary), at least if I did my math correctly, which I'm not sure I did.

Comment: From where did you get equation (1)? Why does $u$ ecist in the denominator of the right hand side?

Answer (score 5):

The thing that comes to mind is the capillary surface including gravity. See the note by Finn, available free as a pdf, as a reference at the end of:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_surface

Hmmm, **maybe not**. Your surface would not have a large flat region in the middle...

A rotated catenary surface is quite simply not isometric to a flat disc. So we might, for instance, be asking about a rubber sheet, glued down along a  boundary, and allowed to sag in the middle under gravity. The elastic energy less resembles the mean curvature operator in favor of the ordinary Laplacian

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_energy

It appears you are looking for the biharmonic equation, as the force of gravity vector field will be considered constant and divergence free, so the displacement $u$ satisfies
$\Delta^2 u = 0.$ See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity#Elastostatics

Comment: Thanks, Will! Your last link especially seems quite useful. But it's leading me to suspect that there may be no cleanly expressible solutions to the differential equations...

Comment: While a water drop may not be it, a soap film would probably obtain the sought after shape, even though inverted. The rubber sheet is probably not a good model as it gets a lower surface density on places where it is stretched out, where it will also need to take a greater amount of force.